# "regretter" avec l'infinitif

Tags: grammaire, verbes, infinitif

Du [Monde](http://www.lemonde.fr/election-presidentielle-2017/article/2016/12/31/primaire-de-la-gauche-bernard-cazeneuve-ne-prendra-pas-parti-pour-un-candidat_5055928_4854003.html):

> Dans son entretien au Journal du Dimanche, il est également revenu sur ses regrets concernant l’action de l’exécutif depuis 2012. « Sur la déchéance de nationalité, j’ai le même sentiment que le président de la République », **qui a regretté le 1er décembre avoir proposé cette mesure** après les attentats du 13 novembre 2015.

Selon un [dictionnaire](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/regretter), on utilise

> regretter d'avoir fait

Alors dans l'extrait, pourquoi est-ce que ce n'est pas "qui a regretté le 1er décembre **d**'avoir proposé cette mesure" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Les deux formes existent : *regretter + inf* ou *regretter de + infinitif*. La forme la plus fréquente est de loin *regretter de + inf*. C'est la seule mentionnée par le [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/regretter) et dans la plupart des livres de grammaire. Cependant [Grevisse](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Bon_Usage) signale l'existence des deux formes* tout en disant que *regretter + inf pur* est rare et ne donne qu'un seul exemple :

> Je regrette surtout ne pas l'entendre ce soir (M. Harry, *Les adorateurs de Satan*, p.33, cit. Sanfeld).

À mes oreilles la forme sans emploi de la préposition sonne plus littéraire, mais cette impression, toute personnelle, vient peut-être du fait qu'elle est peu usitée. En tous les cas elle ne sonne pas incorrecte à mes oreilles. Je pense aussi que c'est une question de style et d'habitude. Par exemple dans [cet autre article du *Monde*](http://www.lemonde.fr/elections-americaines/article/2016/09/11/presidentielle-americaine-j-58-clinton-regrette-d-avoir-stigmatise-des-electeurs-de-trump_4995778_829254.html) le journaliste qui a écrit l'article dit :

> Je regrette avoir dit “la moitié”, c’était mal »

(traduction de l'anglais d'H. Clinton) 
mais le titreur a titré l'article :

> Clinton « regrette » d’avoir stigmatisé des électeurs de Trump

Si *regretter* est suivi d'un nom la seule construction possible est sans préposition (donc suivi d'un COD). *Regretter* peut aussi être suivi d'une proposition introduite par *que*.

<sup>*Malgré ce qui et dit [ici](http://www.cce.umontreal.ca/capsules/verbe-preposition-complement-infinitif.htm).</sup>

Comment: La note vaudrait aussi probablement pour _rêver_ et _se souvenir_ p/r au _LBU14_ ; un moment donné je vais regarder du côté du _Multi_ pour voir, comme c'est aussi une de leur source et qu'elle est plus récente que le LBU14. Aussi j'ai noté que pour un même verbe (différent de celui en question), on a des nuances, comme rêver avec _à_ plutôt que _de_ ou sans préposition : _il rêvait à lui bâtir une brillante fortune_ (Stendhal). Merci !